# Как сравнить 2 массива и удалить одинаковые элементы в них

Tags: c#, массивы, сравнение

Есть 2 массива, первый массив следующего типа:

```
public class ListOfUsers
{
    public Guid idUser { get; set; }    
    public string FIO { get; set; }
}
```

Второй массив типа `IEnumerable<Guid>`.

```
public ICollection<ListOfUsers> First { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Guid> Second { get; set; }
public ICollection<ListOfUsers> Result { get; set; }
```

В массиве First содержится уникальный идентификатор пользователя и его ФИО. В массиве Second содержаться только уникальные идентификаторы пользователей. Как мне сравнить эти массивы следующим образом:

Если элемент массива First есть в массиве Second, то пропустить его. Если его нет, то добавить этот элемент в массив Result и по окончанию отсортировать массив результатов по полю FIO?

Пытался сделать следующим образом, но у меня все дублируется столько же раз, сколько элементов в массиве Second:

```
foreach (var second in Second)
{
    foreach (var first in First)
    {
        if (second != first.idUser)
        {
            Ressult.Add(new ListOfUsers
            {
                idUser = first.idUser,
                FIO = first.FIO
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у HashSet есть метод [`ExceptWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb299875(v=vs.110).aspx) Только тип должен быть одним и тем же

Comment: @Grundy по этому и задал вопрос, что типы не совпадают и нужно как то придумать как это правильно сделать

Comment: Не знаю куда написать, но Second лучше сделать типа HashSet. Тогда из представленного ответа  `Any` вам уже будет не нужен, вместо него используйте метод `Contains`. Из-за того что HashSet хранит хешкоды и ищет по ним, то поиск по нему в вычислительных ресурсах будет стоить меньше.

Comment: Немного советов по коду и наименованиям: вместо idUser, нужно писать UserId, это правильно с точки зрения английского языка и в C# обычно публичные свойства пишут с заглавной буквы. Далее у вас класс называется ListOfUsers (что переводится "список пользователей") но ваш класс не является сам списком, это всего лишь пользователь.

Comment: Так же раз вы называете переменные на английском, то вместо FIO следовало бы писать FullName (полное имя). Так же есть FirstName (имя), LastName (фамилия), MiddleName (среднее имя, оно же отчество)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вы перепутали местами что и как итерируете (пишете - надо обходить first, а начинаете внешний цикл с second).

Во-вторых, проверку на вхождение написали неправильно.

```
var first = new List<ListOfUsers> 
{
    new ListOfUsers { idUser = Guid.Parse("B7AADF05-1F63-4A20-94B1-9A31F4AB4910"), FIO = "Ivan Ivanov"},
    new ListOfUsers { idUser = Guid.Parse("B7AADF05-1F63-4A20-94B1-9A31F4AB4911"), FIO = "Petr Petrov"},
    new ListOfUsers { idUser = Guid.Parse("B7AADF05-1F63-4A20-94B1-9A31F4AB4912"), FIO = "A K"},
    new ListOfUsers { idUser = Guid.Parse("B7AADF05-1F63-4A20-94B1-9A31F4AB4913"), FIO = "Sanvirtus Sanvirtus"},
};

var second = new List<Guid>
{
    Guid.Parse("B7AADF05-1F63-4A20-94B1-9A31F4AB4910"),
    Guid.Parse("B7AADF05-1F63-4A20-94B1-9A31F4AB4911"),
};

var result = new List<ListOfUsers>();

foreach (var element in first)
{
    var isElementPresentInSecond = second.Any(x => x == element.idUser);

    if(isElementPresentInSecond)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        result.Add(element);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам на самостоятельную работу:

- заменить isElementPresentInSecond с linq на примитивы языка
- отсортировать результат

PS Тема ждёт адских linq-однострочников ;)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, понял свою ошибку)

Comment: `result = first.Where(a => !second.Any(b => a.idUser == b))` - чего адского-то?

Comment: Этот алгоритм слишком накладен, работает за O(n^2) так как вы на каждый элемент в first обходите все элементы в second. Внизу вариант с использованием IEqualityComparer намного лучше и работает за O(n), Microsoft специально его сделали для решения этой задачи.

Answer (score 4):

В качестве альтернативы, можно использовать `HashSet` и его метод [`ExceptWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb299875(v=vs.110).aspx)

Либо метод [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx) из набора LINQ.

В обоих случаях потребуется класс реализующий `IEqualityComparer`. Он может выглядеть так:

```
class ListOfUsersByIdEqualityCmparer : IEqualityComparer<ListOfUsers>
{
    public bool Equals(ListOfUsers x, ListOfUsers y)
    {
        return x?.IdUser == y?.IdUser;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ListOfUsers obj)
    {
        return obj?.IdUser.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Далее код может выглядеть так:

1. при использовании HashSet

   ```
   var result = new HashSet(first, new ListOfUsersByIdEqualityCmparer());
   result.ExceptWith(second.Select(s=>new ListOfUsers(){ idUser = s }));
   ```
2. при использовании Except:

   ```
   var result = first.Except(second.Select(s => new ListOfUsers() { IdUser = s }), new ListOfUsersByIdEqualityCmparer());
   ```